# How can I override CMD when running a docker image?

Tags: docker

I want to inspect a docker image created by someone else with both an entrypoint and cmd specified, for example:

```
ENTRYPOINT ["/usr/sbin/apache2ctl"]
CMD ["-D", "FOREGROUND"]
```

I currently do:

```
docker run --interactive --tty --entrypoint=/bin/bash $IMAGE --login
```

Is there a way to override CMD to be empty (so I don't have to use "--login") ?

Answer (score 241):

You could just enter via `docker run -it --entrypoint=/bin/bash $IMAGE -i` (you 'll launch a new container from the image and get a bash shell in interactive mode), then run the entrypoint command in that container.

You can then inspect the running container in the state it should be running.

EDIT: Since Docker 1.3 you can use `exec` to run a process in a running container. Start your container as you 'd normally do, and then enter it by issuing:

`docker exec -it $CONTAINER_ID /bin/bash`

Assuming bash is installed you will be given shell access to the running container.

Comment: Wouldn't that execute "/usr/sbin/apache2ctl /bin/bash"?  (because your example doesn't override the entrypoint it will use the entrypoint defined in the Dockerfile -- or am I missing something?)

Comment: Is that something which is different for older/newer docker versions perhaps? It certainly runs the entrypoint for me: https://gist.github.com/warpr/26a5cc471dce7fcf9021 .  This is using docker 0.10.0 on Ubuntu 13.10.

Comment: Passing `-entrypoint` overrides the entrypoint. See the edited answer

Comment: I know passing --entrypoint overrides the entrypoint.  But when I use --entrypoint, how do I override CMD to be empty?  (For bash I can use something like -i or --login, but not all entrypoints I might want to use will have an equivalent "dummy" argument).

Comment: At least in Docker v1.11.1 it appears that overriding the --entrypoint also prevents the normal appending of the CMD to the entrypoint. That only seems to happen when the entrypoint is not overridden.

Comment: Why there is a `-i` after `$IMAGE`?

Comment: Julia 1.4.0 returns: `Warning: Pkg.installed() is deprecated`. Do you know any update on how to get the package version now?

Answer (score 57):

See: https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#overriding-dockerfile-image-defaults

Relevant portion:

CMD (Default Command or Options)
Recall the optional COMMAND in the Docker commandline:

```
$ docker run [OPTIONS] IMAGE[:TAG] [COMMAND] [ARG...]
```

This command is optional because the person who created the IMAGE may have already provided a default COMMAND using the Dockerfile CMD. As the operator (the person running a container from the image), you can override that CMD just by specifying a new COMMAND.

If the image also specifies an ENTRYPOINT then the CMD or COMMAND get appended as arguments to the ENTRYPOINT.

So to do what you want you need *only* specify a cmd, and override using `/bin/bash`. Not quite "empty", but it get the job done 99%.

Comment: Oops, I overlooked a detail. Except for shortening `--login` to `-l` I guess your solution is already as good as it gets.

Comment: Here's a fun thing I saw today:   the command isn't overridden, it's appended.   Here's the PS from inside the container.  Note that the command I added was echo "setting up the db" and the built in command is /usr/bin/geth.  Also I set entrypoint to be "".
`1 ?        Ssl    0:00 /usr/bin/geth echo setting up db`

Comment: The docker reference link no longer works - can't find an obvious replacement for it.

Comment: I just fixed it, but I also found it hard to find ;(

Answer (score 47):

For anyone comming here to override entrypoint AND command to pass other command, e.g. run bash instead of entrypoint script and then run some other command with parameters (was not clear to me from other answers):

```
 docker run [other options] --entrypoint '/bin/sh' $IMAGE -c 'npm link gulp gulp-sass gulp-sourcemaps'
```

`-c 'npm link ...'` is parameter for `/bin/sh` so here you may pass any command you would want to run in container. `/bin/sh` is for alpine images, `/bin/bash` most likely for other images.

Comment: just an addtion shell commands should be json based writen , so instead of quoting with single quotes `'...'` use double quotes `"..."`

Comment: Or just pass as many --entrypoint arguments as you want

Comment: this does not seem to work: "exec: \"-c\": executable file not found in $PATH": unknown.

Comment: Check the path in container, maybe it really does not exist. Most of the images have `/bin/sh` but yours might not be that case.

Comment: I think this the best and most complete answer, though as @JimmyObonyoAbor points out, it should be corrected to use double-quotes (`"`).

Comment: @NYCeyes why would you say the example should use double quotes? I don't mind to edit the answer but I need to know why. Both single and double quotes are valid for bash even though they do not behave the same. In this example no string interpolation is done so double quotes are not required.

Comment: Most underrated answer!

Comment: @JimmyObonyoAbor  and \@NYCeyes , in shell, in this context, in this example command, should be absolutely no difference between single and double quotes, and indeed, as \@Aurelijus Rozenas stated, I believe single quotes are preferred.

Comment: To me it say `-c` stands for `--cpu-shares`

Comment: @Ini no, `-c` in this case is a parameter to `sh` to pass command string.

Comment: @AurelijusRozenas No it is not, simply type `docker run --help`. You can override the command just by passing it after the image without a `-c` option.

Comment: @Ini you should read the question more carefully. It is about overriding both command and entrypoint.

Comment: @AurelijusRozenas I did. The `-c` option is `-c, --cpu-shares int                 CPU shares (relative weight)` regardless of if you specify `--entrypoint` in addition to that.

Comment: @ini nope. You are looking in `docker run` documentation but this `-c` parameter is meant for entrypoint which, in this case, is `/bin/sh`.

Comment: Sorry, got it. It's because it is specified in place of `[COMMAND]` not as an option in `[OPTIONS]`.